# How to prepend or append the table name to the column name on a view without altering its underlying names in the Database

Tags: postgresql, view

So me and my friends are developing a simple PostgreSQL based project where we decided that a non normalized view of the main table's would be handy

So we quickly did a simple query which worked but we intended to turn it into a view
[image: first query]

We just added CREATE VIEW standard AS, and we noticed that a error appeared,
[image: error]
and we concluded that it was due to us having wrongly named id to various columns spanning 3 tables.

The thing is we don't intend to change the name's of the columns as it would mean rewriting a bunch of the interface's code(in this case python) and it would be easier for us to memorize what is what instead of having to just check the name of the table and then check if we coded it correctly.

This gave us the idea that this problem wouldn't occur if we manually selected every table name and used a As to just rewrite everything to prepend the table name so it wouldn't cause any issues but the now the problem would be manually having to just copy and paste every column name which would create a hard coded query, that in my opinion is a terrible idea as we sometimes add more columns to store new information or maybe in the future we intend to store more complex hierarchical data.

So with the idea that changing the names of the columns would set us back, and hard coding the column names after the select was a bad idea i proposed to them that we could do a sub query to fetch the names of the columns and then prepend or append the table name since this would make the view even better for us to just quickly lookup for info without having to memorize anything.

The thing is i don't have much experience with sql, even less with PostgreSQL  but this was what i managed to get, a query that returns every column that i which to fetch data from

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where information_schema.columns.table_schema='public'
```

[image: my findings]
Now to fix the whole thing i would like to just select each row of the result AS column_name || table_name and add the remaining code as stated above.
Although this caused an issue saying that the sub-query returns more than one result

```
select (select column_name from information_schema.columns where information_schema.columns.table_schema='public') from products inner join collectors on products.id = collectors.id_product inner join measures on collectors.measure = measures.id;
```

`more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

**Is there a solution to this fiasco, optimally one where it would prepend or append the name of the table to the column, without changing the column name or hard codding every column in the select query**
*Also for a bit of disclosure the first id_product is a foreign key related to the first id from products, measure is related to id and they are next to one another "marca and categoria although null will be populated later*
---EDIT:

```
SELECT 'CREATE or replace VIEW standard AS SELECT ' ||
       string_agg(
          format(
             '%s AS %s',
             table_name||'.'||column_name,
             table_name || '_' || column_name
          ),
          ', '
             ORDER BY ordinal_position
       ) ||
       format(' FROM %s.products inner join collectors on products.id = collectors.id_product inner join measures on collectors.measure = measures.id', table_schema)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
  AND table_name in ( 'products', 'collectors', 'measures')
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Based on an answer posted by ___ i've arrived here which is a dynamic query that generates a 1x1 table where in that cell contains the query that when executed creates the view i want. Is there a way to automate this without having to copy-paste like with a procedure or something? i've atempted some tries but it keeps giving me an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple and proper solution is to manually choose an unambiguous alias for each column. After all, you write the view only once.

Automatization of that process only makes sense if you routinely have to create views like that. In that case, it can make sense to use the system catalogs to prepend the table name to the column name. But you can never do that as part of the `CREATE VIEW` statement. You'd have to write code that generates a `CREATE VIEW` statement, then execute that statement.

Beware of SQL injection!

Here is sample code that generates the `SELECT` list for a single table:

```
SELECT 'CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT ' ||
       string_agg(
          format(
             '%I AS %I',
             column_name,
             table_name || '_' || column_name
          ),
          ', '
             ORDER BY ordinal_position
       ) ||
       format(' FROM %I.%I', table_schema, table_name)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
  AND table_name = 'products'
GROUP BY table_name, table_schema;
```

Comment: Alright it's in the right direction but removing the and table_name='buildings' gives me what i want but the thing is isn't there a way to merge the results ie inner join the results into just one view instead of 3 for each table
Also there's no risk of sql injection as this is just a small project+ the view would be a internal one

Comment: There is still a risk of SQL injection - names like `CamelCase` or `has space` will still cause errors, even if no malice is intended. I cannot show a complete solution, because I don't know the query that defines the view. But this should get you close to generating the `SELECT` list, which is the actual problem.

Comment: the query in question is on the first image but to save you time
`select * from products inner join collectors on products.id = collectors.id_product inner join measures on collectors.measure = measures.id;`
Although i've managed to just "port" the code adding this query after the query on format() will inner join as wished but will cause only the columns of a table to be selected even when i remove table_name

Comment: Since i achieved the answer based on this answer i'll accept this one